# I got error "Unsupported lookup 'icontains ' for CharField or join on the field not permitted."

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a dynamic query to get data, like follwing:

```
query = request.GET.get('q')
kwargs = { '{0}__{1} '.format('first_name','icontains'):query}
if query:
    players_list = players_list.filter(Q(**kwargs)).distinct()
```

then I got this error:

> Unsupported lookup 'icontains ' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

If I replaced this line 
`kwargs = { '{0}__{1} '.format('first_name','icontains'):query}`

with this

```
kwargs = { 'first_name__icontains':query}
```

I got no errors 
can anybody tell me what's the difference between them ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space before the close quote; delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very error. It turns out I had the "icontains" lookup twice, once explicit and a second one that I appended to every field. Removing the second lookup fixed the problem.