# How to filter sentences from an list of words in array in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I create like books site, I want to show related book by the title of this book, by at least 2 words to be accurate in suggest books, Firstly I split the title of the current book into an array of words like `['good', 'book', 'by', 'mickle']` and filter the books using `title__icontains` but it shows an empty list

My question is how I can filter sentences from a list of words in an array?
and if there is a better way to get the related objects by title at least two similar word from the title

My Book title

```
   class Book(models.Model):
       author = models.models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True)
```

My function to get the related books by title.

```
class BookRelatedObj(ListAPIView):
serializer_class = BookRelatedSerializer
lookup_field = 'title'
def get_queryset(self):
    book_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    book = Video.objects.get(pk=book_pk)
    lst = book.title
    split = lst.split()

    print(split)
    return Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=[split])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `Q`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    book_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    book = Video.objects.get(pk=book_pk)
    lst = book.title
    split = lst.split()

    return Book.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=split[0]) & Q(title__icontains=split[1]))
```

this get the first and secon word of title and try to get a books with titles that contains this words

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a split list for accuracy
Django is smart enough to get the required accuracy

But if you need to implement your solution you can edit your query to

```
Book.objects.filter(title__icontains__in=[split]
```

We have put `_in` the query because you search items in list not search by word

Comment: It shows this error `Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for CharField or join on the field not permitted, perhaps you meant icontains or contains?
`

Comment: look at this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176275/12392336

Comment: Thank you for your answer I looked to the solution but it seems to not fit to this problem becuase I don't have space between my quot `Book.objects.filter(title__icontains__in=[split])`

Comment: `title__icontains__in` is not supported unfortunately. It should just be `title__in`

Comment: You can use `iregex` to support case-insensitive `in`: 
`Book.objects.filter(title__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(lst.split()) + ')')`

Comment: @bdbd thank you this worked but it is render book if it is have one common word how I can let this at least two common word in title